# VS code api how to support customizable variables in settings?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, text-editor, vscode-extensions

I am currently using typescript to write an extension for VS code.

The extension is trying to create fancy comments for C like languages to improve readability and code structure as follows

[image]

Currently I align the comments at 90 characters, but I would like to allow the user to define whatever alignment they want, as well as allow for custom filling characters

How can I get a settings variable declared in settings.json?

EDIT:

The code:

```
const config = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration('settings');
vscode.window.showInformationMessage(config.has('maximum').toString());
```

Returns false despite the inclusion of

```
"configuration": {
    "maximum":
    {
        "type": ["integer"],
        "default": 40,
        "description": "The level of alignment, how far the titles will extend horizontally"
    }
}
```

In the contributes section of the package.json file. I have gone to both the online documentation and the source code and it's not clear to me how to read user setting values.

Which JSON file should be modified and what parameters need to be given to getConfiguration()? The API does not clearly explain what the parameters to taht function are

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```typescript
// launch.json configuration
const config = workspace.getConfiguration('launch', vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri);

// retrieve values
const values = config.get('configurations');
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#WorkspaceConfiguration